# How do i make it so that the program counts in an ascending order instead of descending?

Tags: java

I just want to know
how to change the counting order from descending to ascending

```
  public class Example5{
    
       public static void main(String[] args){
          int count;
    
          count = Console.readInt("Enter a number: ");
          while (count > 0)
          {
             System.out.println(count);
             --count;
          }
       }
    
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaiPE.png)

Comment: I encourage you to try to figure this out yourself. Play around with the code, try things out, see what you can come up with. Don't be afraid to rearrange things. You'll learn a lot more that way than by asking us how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear as to the reason why you're needing this, but hopefully this helps.  Here is an example of using a for loop for both descending and ascending examples.

Here is an alternative using a for loop for descending...

```java
int count = Console.readInt("Enter a number: ");

for ( int i = count; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

This would be for ascending...

```java
int count = Console.readInt("Enter a number: ");

for ( int i = 0; i <= count; i++ ) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: As noted in the other question's comments, the for loop is nice in that you can box in the range so you have a greater degree of control.  Of course you are the mercy of the user in what they enter, so large values could cause issues.  One idea, since this is just a simple example, is to provide a limited number of numbers, such as 10.  So it could go in either direction, even negative, and you know it will be a finite number of results.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int count = Console.readInt("Enter a number: ");
  for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
    System.out.println(j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Possibly just switch —count; to ++count;

Comment: That will count from the number entered up to infinity.